# Wordpress single.php page - limit text

Tags: wordpress

I am coding website in wordpress, but there are some simple problems. But I don't know how can I fix this. So I need your help.

First problem is that the text goes outside the web, that's not what I want. Then I want to limit text and when it's let's say 2500 words then = page 1 out of 2.

Here's the picture. http://shrani.si/f/2J/kj/1UNhd0Wx/capture.png

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a function for word trimming: [wp_trim_words](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words).

But thats not exactly what you asked for. I don't think there's any built-in way to do what you wanna do, but I'm certain its possible. I would use javascript for this, or else you'd be passing string-offsets to your PHP scripts and thats just naaaasty.

A quick google search for "JavaScript Autopaginate" turned up [this little guy](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/virtualpagination.htm). It seems to be able to do what you are asking for, but I've never used it so YMMV.